# C++ Incorrect standard deviation calculation using std::accumulate

Tags: c++, statistics, standard-deviation, accumulate

I use the following code to calculate standard deviation:

```
std::vector<float> k = {4,6,2};
float mean = 4;

float sum = std::accumulate(k.begin(), k.end(), 0, [&mean](float x, float y) {
    return (y - mean) * (y - mean);
});

float variance = sum / k.size();
float stdev = sqrt(variance);
```

`std::accumulate` returns `4` when it should return:

```
(4-4)^2 + (6-4)^2 + (2-4)^2 = 8
```

Furthermore, printing `(y - mean) * (y - mean)` gives:

```
0
4
4
```

So, why doesn't it return `0 + 4 + 4`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not use the x parameter. Try the following:

```
float sum = std::accumulate(k.begin(), k.end(), 0.0F, [&mean](float x, float y) {
    return x + (y - mean) * (y - mean);
});
```

UPDATE: init value as float

Comment: So, that's why it actually returned only the last value. Thank you very much